# Handing model and viewmodel in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I am creating MVC application and have a question regarding the use of view model and model in my application.

I have extra fields in the view model to be displayed on the screen while i need to send only some while saving the record. For example please see the code below

**ViewModel**

```
  public class Team 
        {
            public int TeamID { get; set; }
            public string CountryCode { get; set; }
            public string TeamName { get; set; }
            public string TeamDescription { get; set; }
            public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
            public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
            public DateTimeOffset? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
            public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        }
```

I need to display the fields CreatedDate ,CreatedBy,ModifiedDate,ModifiedBy on the view.

I have another model called TeamIn which I want to use it while saving the records. This does not contain fields CreatedDate ,CreatedBy,ModifiedDate,ModifiedBy .

```
public class TeamIn : BaseEntity
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int TeamID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Country Code")]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Team Name")]
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Team Description")]
        public string TeamDescription { get; set; }

    }

  public abstract class BaseEntity
    {

        public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

My view however references the TeamIn model which currently has all the fields that i need to display. However I dont want to pass the reatedDate ,CreatedBy,ModifiedDate,ModifiedBy while saving and or updating. Could somebody show me the best way to do it

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<CC.GRP.MCRequest.Models.TeamIn>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Admin/_AdminMenu.cshtml");


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MCR Team Administration";
}


<div class="grids" id="teamGrid">


    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CC.GRP.MCRequest.Models.TeamIn>()
    .Name("GridTeam")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.TeamID).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(o => o.CountryCode);
        columns.Bound(o => o.TeamName);
        columns.Bound(o => o.TeamDescription);
        columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedBy);
        columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedDate);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ModifiedBy);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ModifiedDate);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(250);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
     .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
     .TemplateName("TeamEdit")
        .Window(w => w.Width(500))
     )
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(t => t.TeamID))
        .Create(create => create.Action("Team_Create", "Admin"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Team_Read", "Admin"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Team_Update", "Admin"))
        .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("Team_Delete", "Admin"))
    )
    )
```

**Create Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Team_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Team team)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (team.TeamID == 0)
            {
                mcrRepository.CreateTeam(team);
                return Json(mcrRepository.GetTeams().ToDataSourceResult(request));
            }
            else
            {
                mcrRepository.UpdateTeam(team);
            }
            return null;


        }
```

**Read Controller**

```
public ActionResult Team_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
         return Json(mcrRepository.GetTeams().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Team_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, TeamIn team)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (team.TeamID == 0)
            {
                mcrRepository.CreateTeam(team);
                return Json(mcrRepository.GetTeams().ToDataSourceResult(request));
            }
            else
            {
                mcrRepository.UpdateTeam(team);
            }
            return null;


        }
```

Comment: Agree with Win, you've got it somewhat backward - Team is your ViewModel (recommend naming it TeamViewModel or TeamModel). That is where your annotations, validations should exist. Bind your grid to that (`Grid<TeamViewModel>`) and then in your controller map it to the entity model. AutoMapper has some cool features like Project so you can write code like `respository.GetTeams().Project().To<TeamViewModel>();`

Comment: public ActionResult Team_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(mcrRepository.GetTeams().ToDataSourceResult(request).To<TeamViewModel>, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: When i try this i get an error message that there is no extenstion method 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Win's answer is spot on, but to augment my comment here is my example using Automapper 4.1, in other versions the syntax is `.Project().To<MyViewModel>()`

```
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;

public JsonResult ReadMyStuff([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var myStuffListVM = _db.MyStuffs
             .Where(m => m.Type == "XXX")
             .ProjectTo<MyStuffViewModel>();
    var response = myStuffListVM.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

EDIT: For updates, just reverse the process as @Win has suggested. Go get the entity model and replace with view model changes. Kendo will know you are passing the view model, so your create and update are fine as is:

```
public ActionResult Add([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, MyStuffViewModel myVM)
{
    if (myVM != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var myEntity = Mapper.Map<MyEntity>(myVM);
        _db.Applications.Add(myEntity);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Json(new[] { myVM }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. I shall give this go. I have a final question regarding automapper. How am i going to tell my create controller to pass team model to the dataaccess instead of teamviewmodel

Comment: See my edit, you pass the view model back in and map it to the entity as @Win has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont want to pass the reatedDate ,CreatedBy,ModifiedDate,ModifiedBy
>   while saving and or updating. Could somebody show me the best way to
>   do it

I *personally* do not like using Entity/Domain class in View. *Mainly, I do not want to decorate entity/domain class with data annotations used for validation in view.*

As you said, Team is a ViewModel. Then use it in View. If it doesn't satisfy the requirement of the View, then create another ViewModel class.

In my sample project at [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin), ***[User View](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Areas/Administration/Views/Users/List.cshtml#L54)*** uses ***[UserModel](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Models/Users/UserModel.cs)*** which is different from ***[User](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Libraries/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Core/Domain/User.cs)*** entity.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UserModel>()
   .Name("userGrid")
   .Sortable()
   .Pageable(pageableBuilder => pageableBuilder.Refresh(true)
         .PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000 }))
   .Columns(columns =>
   {
       ...
   })
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
       .Ajax()
       .ServerOperation(true)
       .PageSize(10)
       .Read(read => read.Action("List", "Users").Data("additionalData"))
       .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Id))
       .Events(events => events
      .RequestStart("requestStart")
      .RequestEnd("requestEnd")
      .Error("displayGridError")))

   )
```

FYI: I use ***[AutoMapper](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Mapper/AutoMapperConfiguration.cs#L36)*** to map Entity/Domain to ViewModel and vice versa. When you use AutoMapper, you can specify what property you want to ignore while mapping like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Mapper/AutoMapperConfiguration.cs#L40).

Comment: I am bit confused. I understood the part where you mentioned that annotations are to be used only in the view model. When I am saving the data I need not pass created date and modified date as that is handled by the storedprocedure. So my understanding is that my view model should contain created date and updated date as I am going to show it on the grid while my entity should not contain created date and updated date. Is that correct. I should then use automapper to map both the models.

Comment: Or does my domain entity need to contain all the fields for the mapping to work ?

Comment: In your scenario, Kendo Grid uses same ViewModel to create/edit and display grid, so you need to have CreatedDate and Updated Date properties. ***Do not save posted data straight to database.*** Instead, before updating data, you retrieve the existing record from database, and update only the fields that required like [this edit](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Areas/Administration/Controllers/UsersController.cs#L158).

Comment: Alright , I shall update based on Id.I understand that the viewmodel shold contain the date fields But what about domain entity class. Should it contain all the fields

Comment: Normally, your domain classes *should*  reflect database tables especially if you use Entity Framework. If you have CreatedDate and UpdatedDate columns in database table, you should have those in domain class.

Comment: I have done the mapping. How do I return the viewmodel from my controller.  I have posted my controller code

Comment: Please look at my sample code which use Kendo UI grids. Here is [one](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Areas/Administration/Controllers/SettingsController.cs#L35)

Comment: I had a look. But couldn't relate to my implementation. I am returning a Json and want to return the results in my viewmodel to view

Comment: There are so many ways to use Kendo UI. I normally have search feature for which I need to use POST instead GET [like this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Content/Images/AdminApplicationLogs.png). I'll not continue discussion to chat. If you have more questions about Kendo UI, please create a new question. I'm glad to look at it.

Comment: My question isnt related to kendoui. All I am looking for is how should the controller return the data. Currently I have created two models. One is called Team which is domain entity and the second is TeamViewModel which needs to be passed to my view. The repository method is currently passing data using Team model. My controller needs to pass the viewmodel to the view. I am getting an error saying that the grid is expecting team and you have provided teamviewmodel